# HTML Form GET variables to URL variables

Tags: javascript, html, forms, flask

Alright so I have a regular search form (`method="GET"`). The issue is that the controller for it expects a url like this:

`search/<category>/<int:page>`

My question is, how can i make it so that the above URL is redirected, rather than:

`/search?q=jfiejfiaj`

Do I need to use JS or can I do it in pure HTML?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10622787/1387612) is similar question and [there](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/how-to-post-forms-to-clean-rewritten-urls) complete instruction. I'm afraid that you need to use JS or mod_rewrite on server

Comment: On clicking search, are you redirecting page to that URL? or are you fetching search results with AJAX and displaying result using Javascript?

Comment: I think you're talking about ASP.NET MVC!

Comment: @sabithpocker no it's just a regular form with action and method attributes.

Comment: @janisz yes I feared that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an MVC approach to an web application? You will need to use mod-rewrite on Apache to on the server change the url request.

---

EDIT:

Im not sure if there is a better way using the html form itself but send the html form to a page with either of these, or even better: both.

Meta (Html): (Using php)

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://stackoverflow.com/?search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>">
```

Javascript: (Using php)

```
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com/?search=<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>";
```

Comment: I am using Flask. I guess I am using a MVC approach: I have controllers, templates, and models folders. I am asking as to whether I can have a form submit request to `/search/<searchterm>` instead of `/search?q=query`. I thought a possible solution could be to capture the submit event with JS and manually redirect to the search URL. How could this be done? Is this the optimal solution?

Comment: Im not sure if there is a better way, But you could submit the form to a small custom php script what would redirect to the requested page.

You could use php to echo the form's search term inside a url for redirection. To actually redirect you could use php or javascript.

I edit my answer and place in some example code.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to know if there was another way.

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure HTML. You could attach a submit event handler to the form, prevent the default submit, build a new url with the params on your form and then redirect. However that's a very horrible solution for just getting pretty urls.

Ignoring that, this is how I would do it:

```
<form method="get" action="/search">
<input type="text" name="keyword" />
<button>Search</button>
</form>
<script>
$('form').submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    var params = [];

    $('input', form).each(function(i, item) {
        var input = $(item);

        params[input.prop('name')] = input.val();
    });

    url = form.prop('action');

    for(var param in params) {
        url += '/' + encodeURIComponent(param) + '/' + encodeURIComponent(params[param]);
    }

    document.location = url;

    return false;
});
</script>
```